# JMeter Summary Report % Error

Tags: web-applications, jmeter

I just develop a web apps, and test it using jmeter. Anyway I'm new in jmeter, still not familiar with it.

All test is good, except there is 100% on % error column. I still wondering what is it based, I test it using browser, it working properly, I'm using 1 instance/ 1 request, still it show 100% error.

What Error % column in Summary Report based on? And how I know what error it found which I don't know? Many thanks.

Comment: Did you find answer to your question ? Please gve feedback ...

Comment: thank you. Now can show on the test, it didn't record the authorization. It shows http error 401 in tree result listener.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a tree result listener to your test plan and run it with 1 user, you will get more infos on error.

This error tells you either request failed or response failed based on assertion made (text , response code ...)

Read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html

To understand jmeter concepts.

Regards

Comment: Useful suggestion thanks, however you're unlikely to see the same errors when only using 1 user (e.g. 500 errors indicating server overload). This worked for me with my target user load (see my answer). Also, the link to the general help docs isn't all that helpful - this question is very specific and that link is for very broad info.

Comment: Overload usually gives error 503, not 500 (in an application that follows best-practices).

Answer (score 0):

Seems your test is not running as expected. If you are running against anything that is live the ideal error rates should be 0% or tending to it (unless the application is down or you are testing something negatively).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Server Hits per Second", Available in the Plugin Standard Set.
http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=HitsPerSecond

Answer (score 0):

I accessed errors by Adding a *new* 'View Results Tree' listener. There were 2 existing 'View Results Tree' nodes in my Test Plan, but I added the new one this way:

- Right-click 'Test Plan' node
- Add > Listener > View Results Tree

This added a new listener under my 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder' node. I then re-ran my test with a large number of users (not 1 user, as the accepted answer suggests), and the errors are then all available under the 'View Results Tree' node.